# How to solve the following double integral?

Tags: calculus, integration

We do have:

$\int\int_{D} \frac{xy}{y^{2}-x^{2}}dxdy$

Being **D** the region limited by the curves:

$x^{2}-y^{2} = 1$

$x^{2}-y^{2} = 4$

$\frac{x^{2}}{16}+\frac{y^{2}}{4} = 1$

$\frac{x^{2}}{4}+y^{2} = 1$

My attempt from the hint:

Should I solve for this integral?

$\int\int_{D} \frac{5x^{2}y^{2}}{y^{2}-x^{2}}dxdy$

How could I get the extremes of the integral from the four equations given?

Thanks

Comment: Why did I receive negative feedback? I could update my question showing my attempt if need be

Comment: Yes it should be better if you show your work and effort here.

Comment: @gimusi Please if you could provide more details in why you set up the integral like you did, I may understand it better. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Make a sketch of the domain

[image]

and for symmetry we can deduce that the integral over the four part of the region delimited by the curves is equal to zero.

To evaluate the integral for the first quadrant let

- $u=x^2-y^2$
- $v=\frac{x^{2}}{4}+y^{2}$

then $$dudv=|J|dxdy=\begin{vmatrix}2x&-2y\\\frac x 2&2y\end{vmatrix}dxdy=5xy>0$$

thus

$$\int\int_{D} \frac{xy}{y^{2}-x^{2}}dxdy=2\int_1^4dv\int_1^4 -\frac1udu=-6\ln 4$$

Comment: Could you provide more details in your solution please? I am not getting your answer